# Screen inside another screen is possible in caliburn micro

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I am adding Screen inside another screen in caliburn Micro wpf. Is it best practice? If it is best way, Why?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it. Take a look on a documentation before ask, and please form your questions properly.

Here is an example of multiple views rendering using Caluburn Micro:

[Add multiple views inside a view using WPF and Caliburn.Micro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7879711/add-multiple-views-inside-a-view-using-wpf-and-caliburn-micro)

Comment: Thank you, for your valuable information